# Does "trap" make sense in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, idioms

> The non native speaker does not want to fall into the trap of using a foreign strange word.

Does the word ***trap*** in the above sentence make sense in context?

Comment: As a native speaker, somehow the phrase "foreign strange word" feels just a little bit off to me (but perhaps others would disagree?) I think it has to do with the nuanced concept of adjective order described here: https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/ ... in the end "strange foreign word" feels more natural to my ears.

Comment: Agreed. "Foreign strange word" does not obey correct adjective order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the usage of the word "trap" and the idiom "fall into the trap" sound totally fine to my native speaker ears.

See also: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+into+the+trap+of+(doing+something)
and: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-into-the-trap-of-doing-something

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please back up your answer with supporting authoritative sources. See [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @niamulbengali thanks for the hint! I've added 2 sources 